# Does F# have a OCaml type t equivalent?

Tags: f#

With OCaml variants, I see

```
/* Reason syntax */
module M = {
  type t =
    | Foo
    | Bar;
};
```

quite a bit. F# seems to share the variants leaking into the parent module problem OCaml folks get around with modules.

Does the F# community do something similar?

```
module M =
    type MType = | Baz
    type T =
      | None
      | Foo
      | Bar(MType)
```

Comment: From what I have seen so far, this usage does not seem to be widespread in the F# world. Given that having to write ``M.t.Foo`` can become a bit awkward, I think it is mostly useful for building ADTs (abstract data types) where you cannot access the internals of the type from the outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In F# it is valid to give a type and a module the same name, so it is more common to write a type and its related module side by side like this:

```
type M =
    | Foo
    | Bar

module M =

    let f (m: M) = // ...
```

It used to be necessary to add an attribute `[<CompilationRepresentation (CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]` to the module to do this, but it is now automatic.